# Completing the square question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[This page](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/completing-square.html) provides two examples of completing the square.  The first example adds the area that completes the square to the equation.  I think both examples forget to set the equation equal to zero in the examples.  Is this true?   I set the equation equal to zero in the second example to solve.  Also, in the first and second equations what are the next steps to solve for $x$?

$x^2 + bx$

$x^2 + bx + (\frac b 2)^2 = (x + {\frac b 2})^2$

The second example:

$x^2 + 6x + 7$

I'm assuming this should be equal to zero, which results in:

$x^2 + 6x + 7 = 0$

Then adding the missing area to both sides:

$x^2 + 6x + ({\frac 6 2})^2 + 7 = {\frac 6 2}^2$

$x^2 + 6x + ({\frac 6 2})^2 + 7 - {\frac 6 2}^2 = 0$

$(x + ({\frac 6 2})^2)^2 - 2 = (x + 3)^2 - 2 = 0$

To solve?

$\sqrt {(x + 3)^2} = \sqrt 2$

$x = \pm \sqrt 2 - 3$

Comment: You should use parenthesis where needed. $\frac{6}{2}^2$ is not the same that $\left(\frac{6}{2}\right)^2$

Comment: You can complete the square for a quadratic *function*. You do not need to be solving an equation. But in your first question, you talk about solving for $x$ when there is no equation. $x^2+2x = (x+1)^2-1$ is a valid equation of functions, regardless of whether we're solving $x^2+2x=c$ for some constant $c$.

Comment: @peterwhy thanks updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completing the square is an algebraic rearrangement of a quadratic polynomial, so, for example
$$
x^2 + 6x + 7 = (x + 3)^2 - 2 .
$$

You can use that rearrangement to solve a quadratic equation since it tells you which values of $x$ (if any) make the function $0$, but it has other nice uses.

In the example above you can conclude that the quadratic attains its minimum value of $-2$ when $x = -3$ and that the graph is symmetric about the vertical line $x = -3$.

Comment: Yes I see that, is the solution I added to end of OP correct?

Comment: @Nick OK, Let's delete these comments. For future work - do check your solutions by seeing that they work in the original equation. That will catch many errors.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to keep the distinction clear between a quadratic polynomial *expression* vs. a quadratic polynomial *equation*. The former is simply an expression of the form $ax^2 + bx + c$ or in vertex form $a(x + d)^2 + e$. The latter, is as you've suggested, an equation
$$
ax^2 + bx + c = 0.
$$

You can always convert a polynomial expression between the two forms without ever setting it equal to zero. In other words, you're just manipulating the form of the expression. The main idea is that at every step the expression is *equivalent* to other steps. So,
$$
\begin{align}
ax^2 + bx + c 
&= a\bigl(x^2 + \tfrac{b}{a}x) + c \\
&= a\Bigl(x^2 + 2\bigl(\tfrac{b}{2a}\bigr)x + \bigl(\tfrac{b}{2a}\bigr)^2 \Bigr) + c - a\bigl(\tfrac{b}{2a}\bigr)^2 \\
&= a\bigl(x + \tfrac{b}{2a}\bigr)^2 + \bigl(c - \tfrac{b^2}{4a}\bigr), 
\end{align}
$$
which is of the vertex form, with
$$
\begin{cases}
d = \tfrac{b}{2a}, \\
e = c - \tfrac{b^2}{4a} = \tfrac{4ac - b^2}{4a}.
\end{cases}
$$

Now **if** you choose to set either of these expressions equal to zero, then they will have the same solution set, **but you don't have to.**

Comment: $ax^2 + bx + c = a(x^2 + bx) + c$ these are equivalent?

Comment: Just a typo. Sorry. I'll correct.

Comment: Thank you for catching that, @peterwhy and OP. I'm so used to working with monic polynomials, I just imagined $a=1$ in my head. :-P

Comment: I added a proposed soln for x to the op

Comment: Oh, I've made a mess of this. Haha. *Now* the derivation is correct. Thank you again, @peterwhy.

Comment: Lesson for me: sometimes it's easier to just start over than to surgically modify formulas already on the page.